# How to switch 1st and 2nd , 3rd and 4th, etc elements of an array and output in dec in Assembly Language?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm brand new to Assembly Language(MASM) and want to take a word array and switch the 1st and 2nd elements, 3rd and 4th, etc. I know essentially how to do this, but i can't figure out how to put edi into a 16 bit register. Lastly, how would i get it so that it prints the switched values array out in decimal format? This is what i have so far.

```
TITLE ArrayCode
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

 .DATA
    warray WORD 4,9,13,7,5,12,17,2,15,8 

 .CODE
 main PROC

 xor eax,eax
 xor ebx,ebx
 mov esi, OFFSET warray
 mov edi, [esi+2]
 mov ecx, 5

 L1:
 mov ax,[esi]
 ;Want to move edi into bx
 mov [esi+2],ax
 mov [esi],bx
 movzx eax,bx ;Can i use this to fill the 16 bit and move it into the eax, and then use writeDec?
 add esi, TYPE warray     
 loop L1

 ;Want to display array. Maybe another loop? 
 call writeDec

 call WaitMsg
 EXIT
 main ENDP
 end main
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. We can see your code, but explain us where are you stacked.

Comment: You need to load both before you overwrite `[esi+2]`.  But yes, word sized loads/stores works.  You can make the loads zero-extending into the full reg with `movzx ebx, word ptr [esi+2]` to avoid performance problems from writing partial registers.  Like in [Swapping the pair order of respective elements within an array using indirect addressing in x86 processing assembly language?](//stackoverflow.com/q/58420210) (where the bug was using stores that were too wide.)

Comment: Or of course you can just `rol dword ptr [esi], 16` to swap halves of dword.  Note that `add esi, TYPE warray` only advances 1 element, not 2.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but what does movzx ebx, word ptr[esi+2] do? Don't i want to work with just bx?

Comment: It zero-extends a word from memory into EBX (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx).  Yes, you only care about it as a 16-bit value, but writing BX has to merge with the existing high bytes of EBX.  Doing a zero-extending load is better for performance, avoiding any partial-register performance weirdness.  `movzx` is the "normal" way to load a byte or word in 32-bit x86 code, equivalent to `lbu` or `lhu` on MIPS for example.  Rule of thumb: don't write to partial registers.  Reading narrow registers after writing the full reg is fine, so a word store is still `mov [esi], bx`.

Comment: You could also do stuff like a `dword` load, then word store, shift, and another word store.  But at that point you might as well just rotate and dword store, and then optimize that to a memory-destination rotate.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay thanks for explaining, that makes more sense! As for printing out the array, can i do another movzx of ebx/bx into eax and use that to writeDec?  Since e(bx) is now the first element in the array? Or am i on the totally wrong track here?

Comment: You could do a 2nd loop afterwards, doing `movzx eax, word ptr [esi]` / `call writeDec`..  (Here the `movzx` is actually important because writeDec looks at the whole 32-bit EAX).  Or yes, you print from inside your swap loop, after swapping like `call writeDec` / `mov eax, ebx` / `call writeDec` (assuming you already did movzx leads into EAX and EBX, then swapped by storing.)  You *could* use `movzx eax, bx` but you can just use `mov` because you already took care of widening during the load.

Comment: Using what you've said so far, i `mov ax,[esi]`


Then i  `movzx ebx, word ptr [esi+2]`


Then   `mov [esi+2],ax`

Then  `mov [esi],bx`

then  `add esi, 4`     

And lastly i  `loop L1`

, but for some reason when i step through the program, my 1st and 2nd element aren't being switched, and i'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: UPDATE: I got everything to work and output correctly. Thank you so much for your help!